# Como implementar Actionbar e ViewPager como no Tinder

Tags: android, android-layout

Preciso implementar uma `ActionBar` e `ViewPager` como no Tinder.

Quando o Tinder abre, você pode deslizar por todas as abas.

A segunda aba é uma `ListView` ou uma `ListFragment` e quando você toca em um item, é levado para uma outra série de abas. Você pode deslizar de volta e estará na série de abas anterior.

Como posso fazer isso suave e elegantemente?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que tal colocar umas fotos? Nem todos aqui tem ou podem ter o Tinder no celular. :)

Comment: Vou colocar fotos. Muito obrigado Pablo pela sugestao.

Comment: Como assim, abas do estilo whatsapp também?

Comment: Abas como no whatsapp. Diferente do whatsapp entretanto, na medida que #1- as abas no whatsapp formam uma tabbar abaixo da actionbar e no tinder as abas formam uma tabbar dentro da actionbar; #2- o whatspp tem somente 3 abas simplesmente e nao tem navigation drawer. O tinder tem um grupo (a) de 4 abas e se vc toca num item da segunda aba que e' uma listview ou listfragment vc e' levado para um grupo (b) de duas abas. A primeira aba e' um chat como whatsapp e a segunda aba e' uma horizontal scrollview das fotos que a pessoa disponibilizou. #3- quando vc desliza de volta do grupo 9

Comment: Abas como no whatsapp. Porem whatsapp:
#1- tem abas que formam uma tabbar abaixo da 
actionbar; 
tinder tem abas dentro da actionbar.
#2- whatspp tem 3 abas e nao tem navigation drawer. 
Tinder tem 1 grupo (a) de 4 abas - 
vc toca num item da 2a. aba que e' uma listview ou listfragment vc vai
para um grupo (b) de 2 abas. 
no grupo (b) - 1a. aba e' um chat - 
2a. aba e' 1 horizontal scrollview. 
#3- qdo vc desliza de volta do grupo 
(b) vc volta para a aba nro 2 do grupo (a) e para a aba nro 1 do grupo (a). 
A transicao e' perfeita entre grupos (a) e (b).
#4- o tinder tem navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Selecionei esta Lib : [CardStackView](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView)

> Modo de usar

Declare o layout

```
<com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_card_stack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

Agora implemente o Botão reverse.

```
final CardStackView cardStackView = (CardStackView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_card_stack_view);
cardStackView.setAdapter(adapter);

View reverseButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_reverse_button);
reverseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        cardStackView.reverse();
    }
});
```

Esta é a forma mais simples de implementar, porém no link acima tem explicações de implantações customizadas.

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago. Vou checar. Mas nao pode ter botao. Tem que ser mesma coisa que o Tinder. Somente swiping.